# How to do "highlighting" on gameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, hover, unityscript

I'm making an block-like game and now I want to implement highlighting block (gameobject) while there is mouseOver that specific block.

I tried something like this (I'm not sure that this is best way to do this, but it's only one I got idea for):

```
#pragma strict

public class BlockSelecting extends MonoBehaviour {


public var hovering : boolean = false;

public var xpos : float;
public var ypos : float;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {

}

function OnMouseExit () {
hovering = false;
}

function OnMouseOver () 
{     
        hovering = true;
        xpos = Input.mousePosition.x;
        ypos = Input.mousePosition.y;
}
function OnGUI ()
{
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(xpos, xpos, 26, 26), (Resources.Load("highlight") as Texture2D));
}
}
```

This is not working, since Texture is not showing where mouse pointer is. Is there something I can't see or is this wrong way to do this? My highlight resource is just an 26x26 (block is 25x25) 2D texture of transparent rectangle, so it looks like it's highlighted...

P.S. My plan is to use hovering boolean to check if player is still hovering, if not texture should be deleted/hidden (any ideas on how to do this?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lets say you want to change the color of the object that mouse is on to red so
you should use `OnMouseEnter` to check if mouse is on your object and `OnMouseExit` for when mouse exits the objects area and we set the it`s color back to its original color that was before changing it

```
private color tempColor;
 void OnMouseEnter()
 {
     tempColor = renderer.material.color;
     renderer.material.color = Color.red;
 }
 void OnMouseExit()
 {
     renderer.material.color = tempColor;
 }
```

Comment: Great way to do this! Thanks!