# How do i create a highlight of my GameObject in unity everytime the cursor is on top of it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseover, highlight

I'm really aiming for specific game objects to become highlighted while my mouse is over them

I've scoured the internet for a solution (or even somewhere to start) and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383837/how-to-do-highlighting-on-gameobject). However it seems unity won't let me change the color of an object i've already set in maya? it changes in the inspector but not on the screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do “highlighting” on gameObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383837/how-to-do-highlighting-on-gameobject) (I selected the wrong item in the flag popup)

Comment: I've tried that solution, however it seems unity won't let me change the color of an object i've already set in maya? it changes in the inspector but not on the screen

Comment: What material/shaders are you using on the object?

Comment: 6 lamberts purely for colour

Comment: My code is creating the lambert and changing it's colour however it seems the original lamerts are appearing still over the top of this new colour

Comment: what do you mean by "creating the lambert and changing its colour"? Please include the code that does that in the question.

Comment: With "6 lamberts" you were referring to the lambert shader in Maya. What shader is on the object's material in Unity? Is it the Standard Shader?

Comment: The originally proposed [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28383837/how-to-do-highlighting-on-gameobject) has nearly verbatim, the exact same accepted answer; improper code formatting included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help you

> This will be attached to all the things that can be higlighted with hovering.
>
> ```
> private Color startcolor;
>  void OnMouseEnter()
>  {
>      startcolor = renderer.material.color;
>      renderer.material.color = Color.yellow;
>  }
>  void OnMouseExit()
>  {
>      renderer.material.color = startcolor;
>  }
> ```

Source: [Best way to "highlight" an object on mouse over](https://answers.unity.com/questions/232180/best-way-to-highlight-an-object-on-mouse-over.html)

Comment: It's best to include relevant code in the answer itself in case the site goes down or the content gets deleted for some other reason. I went ahead and edited this answer to include the content of the linked post verbatim.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm relatively new on the platform and it's the first comments I answer haha, thank you friend!